# How to Secure all REST request and response in Grails

Tags: spring, rest, grails, groovy, shiro

I am working on REST APIs using grails/groovy. I want to secure all the requests that comes in and goes out. I am not sure about where do the encryption and decryption process. I thought about couple of options.

1. Call decryption api from all the controllers end point - which i
   think a bad option
2. Use Grails Filter
3. Shiro filter - we are already using shiro for other purpose.Can it be extended to secure  the REST
       calls?
4. Spring AOP
5. Anything else??

I dont know which one to go for, to make it straight forward that all my REST request and response are secured.I am thinking to go for Option #2. I hope others also would have faced this.Any advice would be a great help for me to decide.Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: in general, with any language, this type of problem calls for using hooks. so, does Grails have hooks?

Comment: What version of Grails? And when you say encrypt/decrypt do you mean SSL, or another encryption algorithm? Or do you just mean that you want to restrict access to authenticated users with sufficient roles/permissions?

Comment: What are your security requirements? I would assume you should use SSL, unless there is sensitive information in the payload itself that should not be viewed within the receiving system. And by Grails Filter, do you mean Spring Security? That's a highly mature security solution.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith, I am using Grails 2.2 and will be soon migrating to 2.3. We are going to call REST api in SSL.I already have basic set up for roles and permissions.But on top of it the request and response in the payload is going to be encrypted. We are using our own algorithm to do encryption and decryption.This is in separate layer which I should be able to call from any of the above options.

Answer (score 1):

I guess filters are a great way to implement this and shiro already comes with the `ShiroSecurityFilters`. In those filters you can easily check for your REST controller and apply special handling. Depending on what you need to encrypt, it could also make sense to think about the `beforeInterceptor` and `afterInterceptor` of the controller class: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that this post can help you:

[Securing Grails REST service for use with mobile applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951313/securing-grails-rest-service-for-use-with-mobile-applications)

Disconsidering the mobile part, tell me if this is your issue.